# PHP, отсортировать массив с timestamp

Tags: php, unixtimestamp

Имеется массив с timestamp-ми примерно с прошлого года (когда добавлялись пользователи). Надумала сделать статистику, но не пойму как можно день за днем отсортировать этот массив, чтобы вышло что-то типа

```
[
  '27.05.18' => 25,
  '28.05.18' => 5
]
```

Где 25 и 5 - соответственно количество пользователей за день. У меня же имеется просто список

```
 ["1597770786","1597771694","1597771715","1597776373","1597776819"],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то мне подсказывает, что информация о зарегистрированных пользователях хранится вовсе не в текстовом файле. Скорее всего - в базе данных. Так почему бы не получить эти данные сразу запросом из БД? Например, если registered_at - поле типа TIMESTAMP, то запрос будет выглядеть как-то так:

```sql
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(registered_at, '%d.%m.%Y') AS registerDate,
  COUNT(*) AS usersCount
FROM users
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(registered_at, '%d.%m.%Y')
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(registered_at, '%d.%m.%Y');
```

Ну а если registered_at - это поле типа INTEGER, хранящее unix timestamp, то запрос будет имет примерно такой вид:

```sql
SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME(registered_at, '%d.%m.%Y') AS registerDate,
  COUNT(*) AS usersCount
FROM users
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(registered_at, '%d.%m.%Y')
ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(registered_at, '%d.%m.%Y');
```

И выполнится быстрее, и возни меньше, и последующая обработка проще - данные уже отсортированы, сгруппированы и готовы к помещению в массив:

```php
$result = [];
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $result[$row['registerDate']] = $row['usersCount'];
}
```

P.S. Варианты запроса представлены для MySQL.

Comment: Да, именно то что нужно) спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
$arr =  ["1597770786","1597771694","1597771715","1564404622","1597776819"];

$result = [];
foreach($arr as $row){
    $date = date('d.m.Y', $row);
    isset($result[$date]) ? $result[$date]++ : $result[$date] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю, для определения количества одинаковых значений в массиве, использовать ф-ю [array_count_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-count-values.php).

Тогда задача сводится к преобразованию значений массива в строки, содержащих дату в формате "d.m.Y" и последующий подсчет, с помощью функции `array_count_values()`, кол-ва одинаковых значений:

```
<?php
$input = ["1597610786", "1597611786", "1597770786", "1597771694", "1597771715", "1597776373", "1597776819" ];

sort($input); // <--- если значения уже отсортированны - строчку можно удалить

$output = array_count_values(
    array_map(
        function ($itm) {
            return date('d.m.Y', $itm);
        },
        $input
    )
);

var_dump($output);
```

Вывод:

```
array(2) {
  '16.08.2020' =>
  int(2)
  '18.08.2020' =>
  int(5)
}
```